# Looking for a wxpython widget that would let user's fill in data like they would in a table

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to have a table like display on one of panels where the user can fill in data into pre-made columns.  I'm not sure what widget will give me this functionality.  I want users to be able to edit elements they have already added, and to easily add another element.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Look at Grid or ListCtrl to create the columns.  I think Grid is a better choice for editing as you can add TextCtrls or the like to the columns.

Answer (score 1):

Try out [CSheet](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.sheet.CSheet-class.html), it is much better and customizable than the standard wxGrid and has similar interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try **ListCtrl** with **TextEditMixin** - it's pretty neat and offers keyboard navigation to move between cells.

Comment: This looks great.  I already went ahead and built the part of my gui I was asking about using a ListCtrl.  It works but wasn't exactly what I had in mind.  Maybe I'll redo it with this if I have time.